# How to modify the Request URI in nginx

Tags: nginx

I have an nginx server on which I need to remove a portion of the requested URI.
Example: The request will come as www.domain.com/removeme/myprofile.jpg and I need to treat it as www.domain.com/myprofile.jpg

/removename from the request URI needs to be removed for all the requests where the URI starts with /removename

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Though you might achieve it without modifying the request_uri, try this out, :)

```
if ($request_uri ~* /removeme/.*) {
  rewrite ^ $request_uri;
  rewrite /removeme/(.*) /$1 break;
}
```